# Flutter "sdkmanager not found in Git Bash"

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, programación-móvil

Tengo un problema con Flutter.

Tengo un error en Git Bash, al agregar la licencia no encuentra el sdkmanager, pero en Android Studio todo parece estar bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En android studio se instaló flutter

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además, se instaló Dart

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo SDK Magener en Android Studio, tengo esas herramientas SDK instaladas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo bien agregado el PATH en el sistema operativo Windows

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cual podría ser el problema? Desinstalé y reinstalé Android Studio, pero no puedo agregar la licencia.

Necesito ayuda por favor. Gracias.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. El idioma oficial es español, así que debo pedirte que traduzcas toooooooooooooda la pregunta (incluyendo el título!) 
para que otros te respondan y para que no termine cerrada. 
Recuerda que puedes [edit] la pregunta todas las veces que quieras.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hola, bienvenido, las preguntas en el sitio deben ser en idioma español!, no olvides revisar también [ask] y realizar el [tour] saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Usa "Flutter Doctor", desde la línea de comandos puedes llamarla y ayuda a la instalación y configuración del Flutter SDK.

Revisa: [**Llamar flutter doctor**](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#run-flutter-doctor)

> Desde una ventana de la consola que tiene el directorio Flutter, ejecuta el siguiente comando para ver si hay alguna
> dependencia de la plataforma que necesites para completar la
> configuración:
>
> ```
> C:\src\flutter>flutter doctor
> ```